# How to use analytics mobile app to access firebase analytics data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to use analytics mobile app to access firebase analytics data. I have signed up, and i am owner of app in firebase app settings. But in analytics app, i am getting error:
No Views found
You can try switching account.
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I have the same issue, despite that the website is working

Comment: same here. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere......

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).